# Anaconda python path doesn't seem to have updated

Tags: python, anaconda

when I type in the following to an ipython terminal within Spyder I get the following:

```
import sys 
sys.path 

Out[5]: 
[",'/Users/Bigboat', '/Users'/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python27.zip', 
    '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7',
    '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
     '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
     '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
     '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
     '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa',
     '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
     '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sortedcontainers-1.4.4-py2.7.egg',
     '/Users/Bigboat/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
     '/Users/Bigboat/.ipython']
```

and when I type `python` into terminal I get

`Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:10:39)`

however I've installed python3 using homebrew, I can use python3 in terminal etc. Is there something wrong with the path?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Did you expect the `python` command to be Python 3 instead of Python 2?

Comment: Yes and also with the anaconda I expected it to be .../lib/python3.7...

Comment: The anaconda part of PATH environment variable won't be updated by a homebrew installation. That are two different concepts.